# Spring MVC, Ajax Method Return Type

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am giving user option to upload Images , and I want to do it with AJAX, as soon as user will select a file, jQuery will be used to call a method from my controller using the requestMapping

```
@RequestMapping("/uploadImage")
public void uploadContactImage(@ModelAttribute Contact contact){
 imageUploadService.uploadImage(contact,request);
}
```

What should be ideal returnType of this method as I am not trying to return anything to page, I just want this method to call a method which will do its task. If I use null, it assumes I am trying to return a uploadImage.jsp page,which does not exist.

Comment: The best return type in your case is void which you're already using. Spring will asume the handler handled the response and needs no further processing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use void type.
Also you can mark your method with annotation `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT) or @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)`